# paperjs in win8 JAvaSCript-App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, paperjs

i want to use paperjs in a win8 javascript/html app.

but i alreasy have an error when i just start the app and want to create a

```
Raster("/image/test/mouse.jpg");
```

the error is:

```
Exception in Line 5 ...
JavaScript runtime error: 'Raster' undefined
```

i included the script like this:

```
<script src="/js/paper-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" src="/js/program.js" canvas="canvas-1"></script>
```

so the Raster is defined in the paper-min.js file and it needs to be used in program.js

the first lines of program.js are

```
function makeRasterPicture(imgPath) {
    var test;
    var count = 0;
    var test2 = true;
    var raster = new Raster(imgPath);
```

EDIT:

my script tag:

```
<script src="/js/paper.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" src="/js/program.js" canvas="canvas-1"></script>
```

my canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas-1"></canvas>
```

do you have an tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Paperscript documentation suggests that any code using it should mark its `<script>` tag with `type="text/paperscript"`.

Edit: and you also may want to specify a canvas on which to operate on.

Comment: sry i didnt wrote that. But i already have the correct Type and I also have a canvas. I have edit my post and added that information :-)

Comment: ohh, now that i added the information, i saw that my VS drop that code :-D